# Native camera rendering broken after upgrade to Expo 42(from 39) (React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am using the native camera (iOS/Android) calling as following:

```
  async function takePhoto() {
    const photo = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync(cameraOptions);
    if (photo.cancelled) {
      return '';
    }
    return photo.uri;
  }
```

Since upgraded from Expo 39 to 42 it is broken (see screenshots)

[Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPU4s.jpg)
[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zzip.jpg)

It seems to me, that it is beeing opened as Modal. I don't know where to change this.

Expected behaviour:
Display of camera in fullscreen as native camera under iOS

Update: 20210730: Meanwhile it has been opend as a bug/issue:
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/13614

Any ideas, suggestions - especially in terms of a workaround?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a massive upgrade from EXPO SDK 37 to EXPO SDK 42. Had to change alot of things around camera, location and permissions.

I do not experience this behavior when using the following (I cannot see your import statements or your package versions but this is what I've implemented and experience no issue)

```
// Import statements...
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

// Code within Component
    const takePicture = async () => {

        // You MUST ask for permissions first.
        const permissions = {
            [Camera]: await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync()
        };

        // If denied let the user know its required.
        if (permissions[Camera].status !== 'granted') {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('Camera Permission Required'));
        }

        // Then let them launch the camera and perform any other task
        await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
            allowsEditing: false
        })
        .then(({ uri }) => imageProcesser(uri))
        .then(res => onImageAdded(res))
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    };

// These are my concerning package versions
 "expo-camera": "^11.2.2"
 "expo-file-system": "~11.1.3",
 "expo-image-picker": "~10.2.2",
 "expo": "^42.0.3"
```